# AWS-SDK issue w/ deleteMessageBatch, telling me MissingParameter but I'm not

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm getting the following message

***UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MissingParameter: The request must contain the parameter DeleteMessageBatchRequestEntry.1.Id.***

I think I'm following the documentation to a `T` at [AWS-SDK/SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#deleteMessageBatch-property)

I'm using this code

```
var params = {
          Entries: _.map(_.uniqWith(data.Messages,d=>d.MessageId),d=>({
            Id: d.MessageId,
            ReceiptHandle: d.ReceiptHandle
          })),
          QueueUrl: xx.QueueUrl
        };
await sqs.deleteMessageBatch(params).promise();
```

This is what params looks like at the time of sending; looks just like the docs if you ask me...

```
{ 
    Entries: [
      {
        Id: "83ba1e18-someid", 
        ReceiptHandle: "AQEB79CDI1Q+blablabla"
      }
    ]
    QueueUrl: "https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/somequeeuurl"
}
```

My system:

```
aws-sdk: "^2.354.0",
MacOS - current
node 8.12.0
```

Comment: For someone coming to this thread info: A batch entry id can only contain alphanumeric characters, hyphens, and underscores. It can be at most 80 letters long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MissingParameter: The request must contain the parameter DeleteMessageBatchRequestEntry.1.Id.

I just spent a long time looking at this error and debugging my code.  What I finally figured out is that it seems to be trying to say that there needs to be at least one `DeleteMessageBatchRequestEntry` element in the request – there can't be 0.  When I refactored our code and added a check to make sure that we wouldn't make a request if there were no entries in the list, this problem went away.

Is it possible that you are actually sending the following in certain situations?

```
{ 
    Entries: []
    QueueUrl: "https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/somequeeuurl"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error for the SendMessageBatch:

```
The request must contain the parameter SendMessageBatchRequestEntry.1.Id.
```

I believe the message is trying to indicate that the first entry in your list of entries requires the field `id`.

I solve this by setting the Entry id:

```java
var entry = SendMessageBatchRequestEntry
  .builder()
  .messageBody(body)
  .id(someUniqueID)
  .build();
```